# jaxb don't generate a list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i have this xml

```
<xs:complexType name="ReponseRBType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:ReponseBType">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Elem1" type="tns:OneElem"/>
                <xs:element name="Elem2" type="tns:TwoElem"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

but in the generated Java i don't have a list for Elem1 and Elem2 , only have getter and setter , how to do to generate a list ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 2 lists for each type:

```
<xs:complexType name="ReponseRBType">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:ReponseBType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Elem1" type="tns:OneElem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Elem2" type="tns:TwoElem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

If you want a single list containing both types, just inherit them from the same parent class and make a list of parent type.

Comment: yes i want a single list containing both types, how to inherit them from the same parent class  ? I generate my java using ANT

Comment: Do you generate OneElem and TwoElem from xsd or do you use it from any kind of dependency?